# Prevent href from onclick within component

Tags: html, angular, eventemitter

Within my project I'm trying to create a custom anchor component to centralize styling (icons and such). Basically, a wrapper for `<a href>`.

In some situations I need to bind the `(click)` event for different or additional behaviour. By returning `false` in the click event of anchors, you can prevent the browser from following the href. This means my click will fire on a normal click or tap, but the href will be followed when using the middle mouse button or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd>.

I have no clue how to accomplish this when the anchor resides **inside a component**.

I would have to expose the click event outwards using an `@Output()` event emitter, but this doesn't allow you to return a value (`false`).
The other option would be to bind the function as an `@Input()` property, but then passing arguments to the call becomes troublesome. Binding would be `[clicked]="open"` rather than `(clicked)="open($event, args)"`, leaving no direct room for arguments.

What I'm trying to accomplish would look something like the following:

**SomeGridComponent**

```html
<!-- let-row="row" -->
<app-href [href]="openHref(row)" (click)="open($event, row)"></app-button>
```

```
open(evt: MouseEvent, row: IRowData): boolean {
  if (/* some condition */ true) {
    // do stuff
    return false;
  }
}
```

**HrefComponent**

```html
<a [href]="href" (click)="hrefClicked($event)">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</a>
```

```
@Output() click = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

hrefClicked(data: MouseEvent): void {
  // return this.click.emit(data);
  this.click.emit(data);
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want the `a` tag and not for example a `div`?

Comment: Because I want the default browser behaviour for <a href> anchors. That is, to go to the url regardless of the method used (ctrl+click, middle mouse button, etc). In some cases I want to overrule this for regular clicks using the (click) event.

Comment: Then dynamically change the `href` for those cases. Or just map the click function for any click keybinding. The possibilities are endless.

Comment: @CatalinIancu What exactly do you mean by that? The href should remain the same for ctrl+clicking to behave the same as a regular anchor. Only on a normal click do I want special behaviour (and only if the function returns false based on the arguments). I can't define that ahead of time because it depends on how the end user interacts with the link and what the arguments are.
I also don't understand what you mean with the second part. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Something like this `$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.which=="17")
        cntrlIsPressed = true;
});` It detects when the `ctrl` button is pressed. You can use that to open whatever you need in new tab.

Comment: That's a global listener, though. I'm looking for something specific to Angular components. And ctrl+clicking is just an example that I know of. I don't want to recreate all possible standard browser behaviour that applies to anchors. Thanks for the suggestion though.